# Patching a SharePoint list from a PowerApp?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am trying to program a Power App to be used for streamlining an interview process. The user will select a candidate from a dropdown and then select scores during the interview. On selecting a submit button, I would like the selected scores to be added to empty columns in a SharePoint list in the correct row based on candidate name from the dropdown.

```
Patch('Assessment Center Test Data', 
First(Filter('Assessment Center Test Data', Name = CBI_CandidateDropdown.Selected.Value)),
{ScoreTest : CBI_DR_OverallScore.Selected.Value
}
)
```

The above code is what I tried, where 'Assessment Center Test Data' is the SharePoint list, 'Name' is the column in the list with existing names, and 'CBI_CandidateDropdown' is the name of the dropdown to select the candidate. 'ScoreTest' is the empty column I am trying to add the overall score to.

I get an error on the equal sign after Name and on the .Value after 'CBI_CandidateDropdown'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try with a `LookUp` with the filter `Name = CBI_CandidateDropdown.Selected.Name` instead of `First` & `Filter`

```
Patch(
   'Assessment Center Test Data', 
   LookUp('Assessment Center Test Data', Name = CBI_CandidateDropdown.Selected.Name),
   {
      ScoreTest : CBI_DR_OverallScore.Selected.Value
   }
)
```

If there is still an error, can you share SharePoint structure of list? What is the type of Name, ScoreTest, CBI_CandidateDropdown and CBI_DR_OverallScore?

Comment: Hi, I ended up solving this. All I had to do was change .Value to .Name.

Comment: OK, great! I edit the answer to add the fix on the filter.